# Read scripts on a site using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to write a python script that notifies me through mail when a site updates it's selection of apartments. However, when I use Beautiful Soup, the site doesn't return a list of items, but rather a script that selects all relevant houses instead of the results of said script. Is there any way for me to retrieve the html of text of a site that I would see normally as a user? This is the rather simple code I've written in case that helps.

```
html = #somesite
response = requests.get(html)
text = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
text.find_all("script")
```

Comment: can you share the URL if possible

Comment: plz do us a favor and share the url - if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the (java)script the way web browser does, then parse resulting html. I use selenium, there are other tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
html = #somesite
response = requests.get(html)
text = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
text.text # returns text in the entire html body, excluding script
```

Comment: This only gives me the text inside the html, and not the text from the results of the scripts.